# SELECT DISTINCT values grouping for one columns in Google Sheets Query

Tags: google-sheets

Let´s say I have this set of dummy data in a .gsheet spreadsheet which Sheet is called Sheet11:

[image]

I need to get the following output:

[image]

which means that I´d be `selecting` column A corresponding to the projects, `counting` the users in column B `where` the Billable is equals TRUE, and then `grouping` by A and last `ordering` by the column counted B.

Applying the query formula `=query(Sheet11!A1:C13,"select A,count(B) where C=TRUE group by A order by count(B) desc",1)`, I am getting this:

[image]

It counts all the users assigned to project1 and all assigned to project2, I´d need to get the count of unique users for both projects.

How could I apply some kind of unique like in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subselect:

```
=query(query(A1:C13,"select A,B, count(B) where C=TRUE group by A,B",1),"SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col2) GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY COUNT(Col2) desc")
```

[image]